# Cutting a div with a background image diagonally

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to create a website that utilizes the diagonal sections look. [I am trying to get this kind of angle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xPoz.png)

I also need full browser support. I've seen a lot with the polygon fix, and I've tried rotating the div but it extends my browser width and leaves the top with random white space. If anyone can help out that would be amazing. If you need any clarification please let me know.

```css
.shape {
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.top {
    height:0;
    border-width:0 0 100px 400px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent #d71f55 #d71f55 transparent;
}
.bottom {
    height: 0px;
    background-color:#d71f55;
}

/* Support transparent border colors in IE6. */
* html .top {
    filter:chroma(color=#123456);
    border-top-color:#123456;
    border-left-color:#123456;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been trying this out http://jsfiddle.net/UYRFY/2713/ but the angle isn't the direction I need it and I am having a hard time changing it the right way.

Comment: it looks like you have what you need, just need to reverse the angle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in this example only works in "modern" browsers, but if you add browser prefixes I believe can work back to IE9. It uses a rotated div as the "cut", but puts that div in an `overflow: hidden` container so that you don't get the whitespace you were talking about.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/400/400/);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.cut {
  background: #fff;
  position:absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotate(8deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cut">
  </div>
</div>
```